# SQL Server Char/VarChar DateTime Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Can someone tell me why this code produces error?

The C# code

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime after1month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
```

The query it produce

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE THEDATE BETWEEN 'now' AND 'after1month'
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thx

Comment: Show us the code, which creates and runs this query

Comment: _What_ error are you getting? And _how_ do you create your query?

Comment: That C# code does not generate SQL, so there is other code that is creating the SQL (LINQ to SQL). We need to see that.

Comment: here 'now' and 'after1month'  are considered as string which are not matching to date column value

Comment: @Richard Sorry for my word choice, what I meant by generate is a simply using variable from C# and put it into a connection string..

Comment: @reshma hey do u mind to show me the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Please add the ADO code you are using – without that we're just guessing.

Comment: @Rofans.NET: It all depends on **how** you are putting the C# variables into the SQL command.

Comment: @Richard it has nothing to do with ADO, otherwise I would have include ADO into this question tags

Comment: ADO(.NET) is the underlying way to connect to relational databases in .NET. It will always be there even if you never directly interact with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should look more like this:

```cs
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime after1month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE THEDATE BETWEEN @now AND @after1month", connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@now", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = now);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@after1month", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = after1month);
```

Sometimes you can do it directly on SQL Server side using query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE THEDATE BETWEEN getdate() AND dateadd(mm, 1, getdate())
```

without parameters from .NET.

**Added** (after comment):

[`dateadd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) is a SQL Server function that allows to add a specyfic interval to date and returns it.

In this case `dateadd(mm, 1, getdate())` adds one (`1`) month (`mm`) to current datetime (`getdate()`). More info on datepart identifiers and function itself on [MSDN dateadd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

Comment: @Michael can you elaborate more on this _dateadd_ keyword?

Comment: @Rofans.NET Just try to search http://www.google.lt/search?q=sql+server+dateadd

Answer (score 3):

if u don't want to use ADO then use direct SQL query as

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE THEDATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())
```

Here DATEADD function will add one month into current month by using 'mm' parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'now' and 'after1month' are variables that you are using in your query. What is the datatype of those variables? You need to cast it to datetime type. Use Convert or Cast function of SQL server to do so.

Comment: no they are not variables in this case as single quotes are there.it is considered as string constant